# A simple but nonsense infinite sums rule

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, soft-question, solution-verification, power-series

Assume $a>0$ and $0<r<1$ are given. The geometric series is known to be $\sum_0^{\infty} ar^n = \frac{a}{1-r}$.  Now differentiate w.r.t $r$ to obtain $\sum_0^{\infty}anr^n = \frac{ar}{(1-r)^2}$. So far we're cool.

Now take the two series $$S_1 = \sum_n \frac{1}{2^n}$$ and $$S_2 = \sum_n \frac{n}{2^n}.$$ One would trivially expect $S_2>S_1$, because obviously $S_2$ has an additional $n$ multiplied by each term. To my surprise, this is not the case! Invoking the result of the previous paragraph, you get
$$S_1 = \frac{1}{1-1/2} = 2$$
and
$$ S_2 = \frac{1/2}{1/4} = 2$$
so that $S_1 = S_2$.

Does this make any sense to you? Because it sure makes no sense to me. Or am I losing it?

Comment: What about $n=0$?

Comment: All sums start from $n=0$. I was just too lazy to type it every time :)

Comment: That part was clear, but what do you get for $n=0$?

Comment: 1 for $S_1$ and $0$ for $S_2$?

Comment: And don't you see how that invalidates your argument?

Comment: Limits are weird, and can turn $<$s into $\leq$s. For instance, $\frac{1}{n} < \frac{2}{n}$, and yet $\lim \frac{1}{n} = 0 = \lim \frac{2}{n}$. What you're experiencing here is the same phenomenon

Comment: @saulspatz Each term of $S_2$ is bigger than each term of $S_1$... except for the first term? And that first term is the deal-breaker?

Comment: That's it exactly!  Your argument requires that each term in the second series is at least as large as the corresponding term in the first series, and at least one term in the second series is greater than the corresponding therm in the first series.  No exceptions allowed.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor Actually, that has nothing to do with what's going on.  WimC's comment explains the problem.

Comment: @saulspatz Thanks! I guess the problem is solved then!

Comment: Here's a cherry on top: if you start from $n=1$ instead of $n=0$, $S_2> S_1$ far and away!

Comment: @saulspatz - thanks! Perhaps I posted that comment too quickly.

Comment: @HallaSurvivor I know that feeling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are right $S_1 = S_2 = 2$ and it might be somewhat astonishing the first time. But first let's have a look at your derivation which needs to be somewhat revised. We can take $a=1$ and consider
\begin{align*}
S_1(r)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\frac{1}{1-r}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
Derivation with respect to $r$ gives
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dr}S_1(r)&=\frac{d}{dr}\frac {1}{1-r}=\frac{1}{(1-r)^2}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
Note we have numerator $1$ and not $r$. On the other hand we also obtain
\begin{align*}
\frac{d}{dr}S_1(r)&=\frac{d}{dr}\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nr^{n-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nr^{n-1}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty (n+1)r^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nr^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty r^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty nr^n+\frac{1}{1-r}\\
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nr^n& = \frac{d}{dr}S_1(r) - \frac{1}{1-r}=\frac{1}{(1-r)^2}-\frac{1}{1-r}\tag{3}
\end{align*}

We obtain from (1) - (3) by substituting $r=\frac{1}{2}$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{S_1\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)}&=\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}\,\color{blue}{=2}\\
\color{blue}{S_2}&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{n}{2^n}
=\frac{1}{\left(1-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2}-\frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{2}}=4-2\,\,\color{blue}{=2}
\\
\end{align*}

We observe the term with $n=0$ in $S_2$ is zero, but the numerator $n$ with index $n>0$ is a compensation for it.

Comment: Thanks! The trick was to look at the zero'th term.

Comment: @Erfan: You're welcome! :-)